# R: "Knit to Flexdashboard" Button Doesn't Always Appear?

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

I am working with the R programming language.

I have noticed that when I am working with R markdown, the "Knit to Flexdashboard" button doesn't always appear. For example - over here, it appears:

[image]

And over here, it does not:

[image]

When I open R Studio, I always make to first load the "flexdashboard" library:

```
library(flexdashboard)
```

Then, I click `"File" -> "New File" -> "R Markdown"`

And I create a new document and click "create".

Yet, sometimes I notice that the "Knit to Flexdashboard" button is there, and sometimes the "Knit to Flexdashboard" button is not there.

**Does anyone know why this is happening and what I can do fix this problem?**

Thanks!

Comment: It isn't a problem, by my opinion.  ```output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard``` -> ```Knit with parameters``` and you will see what you want.

Comment: Furthermore you can create a flexdashboard doc straightaway. ```"File" -> "New File" -> "R Markdown" -> "From Template" -> "Flex Dashboard"```

Comment: WOW! The second comment you left was amazing! This is genius! I can't believe I had never thought of that before!

Comment: If you have time, can you please show me an example as to how someone would use the code in the first comment? Thank you so much!

Comment: Had you left an answer here, I would have approved this as the official answer! Thanks again!

Comment: Explore and enjoy the RStudio ;-) Ok, i'll create an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have said in comments above - you can choose output formats for your `rmarkdown` doc manually.

In your case is:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
---
```

Also exists a lot of others formats, look here: https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-9.html and there: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/output-formats.html

They forget to add `xarigan` and I don't see the `posterdown`.

So, you have chosen the required format - push the `Knit with parameters` and voilà.

---

The more lazy variant `"File" -> "New File" -> "R Markdown" -> "From Template"` hasn't all output formats and sometimes you will be forced to choose it manually (or you can prepare your own templates respectively).

Good luck.